# Picasso fetch() and get() with OkHttpDownloader

Tags: android, gridview, picasso, okhttp, remoteview

I am using Picasso library (2.5.2) with OkHttpDownloader (2.4.0) as downloader

```
OkHttpClient myOkHttpClient = new OkHttpClient();
myPicassoInstance = new Picasso.Builder(context).downloader(new OkHttpDownloader(myOkHttpClient)).build();
Picasso.setSingletonInstance(myPicassoInstance);
```

in a RemoteViewsService.RemoteViewsFactory to fill a images' grid prefetching by fetch() in onDataSetChanged() method

```
Picasso.with(mContext)
.load(picture)
.resize(Math.round(160 * displayMetrics.density), Math.round(90 * displayMetrics.density))
.centerCrop()
.fetch();
```

and getting by get() in getViewAt() method

```
Picasso.with(mContext)
.load(itemsList.get(position).getUrlImage())
.resize(Math.round(160 * displayMetrics.density), Math.round(90 * displayMetrics.density))
.centerCrop()
.get());
```

Well, enabling logging on Picasso's instance, I see that at first run fetch() loads from network and writes entries in cache, while get() loads from cache. 
At second time, while updating grid's content, fetch() loads from memory and get() from cache.
And it is ok.

**But when process dies and is restarted, fetch() restarts to load from network ignoring the cache entries, why?**

**UPDATE**
I tried without OkHttpDownloader (2.4.0) as downloader and now fetch() loads right first time from network (if image doesnt exist in cache) or from disk (if image exists in cache), retaining in memory until process dies.

```
myPicassoInstance = new Picasso.Builder(context).build();
Picasso.setSingletonInstance(myPicassoInstance);
```

**then, there is some conflict between Picasso library (2.5.2) and OkHttpDownloader (2.4.0)?**

**UPDATE 2**

- Tried with OkHttpDownloader (2.3.0) as downloader: same problem
- Tried with UrlConnectionDownloader as downloader: same problem
- Tried using into() in an adapter: same problem

Answer (score 0):

[This](https://github.com/square/picasso/issues/1097) reply on github solved my problem.